# Icalendar ICS Rails : How to event directly to my calendar without subscription

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, icalendar

I'm using the `icalendar` gem.

I have gone through icalendar methods but I could not find any useful information. Here's the code I have so far:

```
@calendar = Icalendar::Calendar.new
event = Icalendar::Event.new
event.uid = 'UID333'
event.dtstart = Icalendar::Values::Date.new('20190828')
event.dtend = Icalendar::Values::Date.new('20190829')
event.summary ="THIS IS SUMMARY"
event.description = "THIS IS DESCRIPTUON"
event.location = "THIS IS LOCATION"
@calendar.add_event(event)
@calendar.publish
render plain: @calendar.to_ical
```

I want to add event to my Outlook calendar without a subscription. With above code it is adding event with a subscription under "other calendar" as 'untitled'. My goal is to directly add it to my Outlook default calendar. Is this possible, and if so, does anyone have an example of how it can be done?